# How to create .dll file from multiple files with different extension

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Can I create a single dll file of my project which contain other dependent dlls and some other subfolders which contains file which are not .cs file but use to make calculation in my project.

My project look like this:

[image: Project and folder stucture]

Above image first arrow shows reference which comes after adding dll ex. abc.dll.

And arrows 2 and 3 shows folders in my project which contains file which are used in code. And those are not .cs (C# files).

Is it possible to create single dll which contain all this dlls and files in folders so that I can distribute to anyone.

Or is there any other way I have to follow.

Let me suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use ILMerge to solve combining multiple DLL's into one, found here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx also found in nuget. For the other items, you can add them as resources: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a single interface (ONE DLL) that is using other DLL and your own source code.

But you need to ship other DLLs too with your DLL.  Because without it other people will get error when consuming other DLL functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to package up all the dependencies as resources in your project.